Calculated column based on another column
I'm trying to create a calculated column based on a status column. The status column is a multi choice column (but I can change in a text column).
For example: if the status is "xxxx", I'd like it to return a number
=IF([Status]="Engine on", "40", IF([Status]="Functional check", "50", IF([Status]="Assembly", "80", "0")))

I tried this code but I have an error message on Lists when I confirm it.

What is the error message?

Multiple selection choice columns in SharePoint list are not supported in calculated column formulas.
If you use single selection choice column or text column, you can use calculated column formula like:
=IF([Status]="Engine on", 40, IF([Status]="Functional check", 50, IF([Status]="Assembly", 80, 0)))

Calculated column settings:

Output:

Note:

Sometimes comma(,) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(;) instead of comma(,).
Use correct display name of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
Wrap column names inside [] if your column name has space in it. For example: [My Column Name].


Thanks a lot!!!! The problem was the , instead of ; !!!! Could I ask another thing? If I would say IF the column has the status A or the status B write the same number, how can I say? In this way I will not use the 7 "slot" of IF cicle

For your above query, you can use formula like: =IF(OR([Status]="A";[Status]="B");80;0). Let me know if this works for you.

It works! Thanks a lot!!!! One more thing: I tried also with "Multiple selection choice columns" and it works also in this case!!!!

You are welcome, I am glad it worked for you!

Can you please accept it as an Answer as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. Thanks!
